# Saddling a Ghast

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I heard a rumor that you can put a saddle on a Ghast and ride it like a pig, is this true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no information on the [Minecraft Wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ghast) about being able to to ride a Ghast.

Comment: No, I know that is not possible, [Minecraft Mythbusters busted that.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoPA6xHYny4#t=2m19s)

Comment: I hadn't seen that video, I'll take that out to prevent any misconceptions then.

Answer (score 10):

I just tried; it is indeed impossible.
[image: awkward failed mounting]

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually in range of that ghast.

Comment: So you're riding a Ghast with a saddle in this image?

Comment: The ghast seems sort of meh about this whole situation

Comment: @Kevin: He said *impossible*.... i.e., he isn't.

Comment: Wow, I totally misread that.

Comment: Aren't they giant? A saddle doesn't even fit.

Answer (score 4):

While you can't officially ride a ghast, there are cheaty ways to ride pretty much any creature you wish, and ghasts, thanks to their size will keep the (blatantly visible) cheat obscured. Of course the ghast won't be controllable and will fly wherever it wills, it will also happily attack you in survival mode.

The trick is that any mob can have 'passengers' and any mob can be the passenger. - this allows for spider jockeys, chicken jockeys etc. So you can summon a ghast mounted by a saddled pig. Then you can mount the pig, and you're "riding a ghast":

`/summon minecraft:ghast ~ ~ ~ {Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:pig",Saddle:1b}]}`

[image]

Summoning the ghast with:

```
/summon minecraft:ghast ~ ~ ~ {Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:pig",Saddle:1b,Silent:1b,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:2147483647}]}]}`
```

makes the cheat somewhat less blatant, as the pig becomes invisible and silent. The ghast is still completely uncontrollable and hostile though.

Comment: Makes me wish for a natural `Invisible` flag for Minecarts, like the one Armor Stands and Item Frames have. (Because the Invisibility potion effect does run out eventually. A dedicated flag wouldn't.)

Answer (score 1):

You can ride it with Single Player Commands with /saddle. If you jump on it, you will fall through.

Note that Single Player Commands is a mod. It allows for NBT manipulation beyond Vanilla capabilities. Directly riding a Ghast (without intermediate entity) is not possible in Vanilla (unless you count Spectator Mode's mob perspective feature).

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoPA6xHYny4#t=2m19s ?

Comment: @badp Late reply, but Single Player Commands is a mod that can manipulate NBT in ways that Vanilla won't let you. `/saddle`, for instance, adds you to a mob's passengers instead of using a saddle item. I'll propose an edit to highlight the fact it's not Vanilla.